# Laravel middleware to check user has access - if not do not proceed with controller method?

Tags: laravel

Googled and tried for hours now, i need help. Laravel 9.x here.

I use ajax calls which are handled by controllers.
Before the controller handles them, i need to check if the user has indeed access to the administration the user is requesting data for.

The problem is the return false in the middleware class. How can i return a response to the browser **without executing any method inside the requested controller class**?

The middleware i'm using:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;   

use Closure;

class CheckUserAccessToAdministration {
    
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        //  Check if the user has access rights to the requested administration
        $allowedAdministrations = $request->session()->get('allowed_administrations');
        $administration         = $request->adm;

        if(!in_array($administration, $allowedAdministrations)){
           
            // the idea is that i stop execution of the call, not execute controller method 
               and just return a message to the browser. i use return false atm, but that isn't right, 
               i think.
            return false; 
        }
     
        return $next($request);
    } }
```

Comment: Change `return false; ` to `return "Permission denied";` or send the return in a JSON format.

Comment: Thx! Tried that, i get the following error: Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders(): Argument #1 ($response) must be of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, string given, called in /dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php on line 132.  What can i do now?

Comment: Talked too fast, if i use return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Permission denied'
    ]);  it does work. Thanks!